# SQL Server stored procedure parameter output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I have scaled down considerably for the purpose of this question but in essence the issue I need assistance with is this.

If a row in table `xyz` is updated I need the ID's to be appended to each other and output back to the calling application. The update works as expected, the problem is in the manner in which I am building the output `@IPV_ID_Found` (see commented section at the bottom of the code).

```
@IPV_Status varchar (50),
@IPV_ID_Found varchar(500) = 'A' OUTPUT 

IF (@IPV_Status ='closed')
BEGIN
UPDATE TEST_TBL
 SET
    Status  = 'xyz',        
 WHERE                  
    ID      =  @IPV_ID 

  -- this works for one ID
  SELECT @IPV_ID_Found = (CAST(@IPV_ID AS VARCHAR(500)))    

  -- this does not work for multiple IDs
  SELECT @IPV_ID_Found = @IPV_ID_Found + (CAST(@IPV_ID AS VARCHAR(500))) + ','

  -- neither does this
  SET @IPV_ID_Found = @IPV_ID_Found + (CAST(@IPV_ID AS VARCHAR(500))) + ','

  SELECT @IPV_ID_Found                  
END
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I placed the code within code blocks but It didn't take......

Comment: Hmm... you're updating your table with `ID = @IPV_ID` - how can this result in multiple ID's to be reported back?? What ID's do you want to report back??

Comment: There are not multiple IDs: if you have `UPDATE ... ID =  @IPV_ID`  the `=` means one row. So give better code, sample data

Comment: Hi Marc,I am passing in a comma delimeted varchar of ids to the stored Proc extracting the IDs storing them in a temp table then using the size of the temp table as a loop to do the update. The update works fine The issue is with the way I build the output (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the changes:

```
 -- this does not work for multiple IDs
  SELECT @IPV_ID_Found = @IPV_ID_Found + ',' + (CAST(@IPV_ID AS VARCHAR(500)))
```

then you will get a concatenated list of values, like `1,2,3,4,5`

**BUT** if you need to return a recordset, then you need not OUTPUT parameter, use the table variable instead:

```
declare @IPV_ID_Found table(Item varchar(500))

IF (@IPV_Status ='closed')
BEGIN
UPDATE TEST_TBL
 SET
    Status  = 'xyz',        
 WHERE                  
    ID      =  @IPV_ID 

  -- this works for one ID
  insert @IPV_ID_Found 
  VALUES (CAST(@IPV_ID AS VARCHAR(500)))    

  -- this does not work for multiple IDs
  INSERT @IPV_ID_Found 
  VALUES (CAST(@IPV_ID AS VARCHAR(500)))

  SELECT Item FROM @IPV_ID_Found                  
END
```

Comment: Good Man!!! I went with the recordset, and forgot about the OUTPUT parameter cheers.